# Convert Ansible stat's mtime output to YYMMDD-HHMMSS

Tags: ansible, jinja2, epoch, filemtime

I'm trying to extract a file's last modified time in the format YYMMDD-HHMMSS (ex:210422-135018) using Ansible's `stat` module.

I'm getting the file's `mtime` in a playbook:

```
    - name: stat
      stat:
        path: /path/to/file
      register: file
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ file.stat.mtime }}"
```

Which returns the mtime in EPOCH format (ex: `1632916899.9357276`)

I've tried following instructions in the Ansible docs, but could not get it to work.

Is there a simple way to do this via Ansible, or is it best to do it via the `shell` module?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Solved with help from comment below:

```
    - name: stat
      stat:
        path: /path/to/file
      register: file
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ '%Y%m%d-%H%M%S' | strftime(file.stat.mtime) }}"
```

Comment: Please don't use the language "it doesn't work" when asking others for help. Show what you _did_ try and include the error message or bad outcome you got from your attempt. I strongly suspect you will want to read about [`"..."  | strftime(file.stat.mtime)`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#handling-dates-and-times)

Comment: Thanks for your respone! I apologise if I came across as ungrateful - that was certainly not my intention. I've read the documentation at the link you sent, but it didn't quite 'click' until the example you've added.

Comment: @dkd6, you can also answer your own question and mark them later as accepted answer.